# Laravel get records of distant relations via an intermediate relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder, laravel-relations

There are 3 tables:

1. **users**
2. **personal_access_tokens**

- tokenable_type
- tokenable_id

3. **personal_access_token_cards**

- personal_access_token_id

**Users** has many(morph) personal access tokens.

Each **personal access token** has one **personal access token card**.

How can I get all the personal access token cards for a collection of users?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
User::with('personalAccessTokens.personalAccessTokenCards')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you. is there a way to get an array with some value of personalAccessTokenCards? I mean, i need a straight Array with all "token card" values for all users in the collection